# MySQL Startup Error - Root element missing

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2003, windows-server

I have had MySQL installed for about 2 months on Windows Server 2003 R2. On start up we get presented with an error that says "High Severity Error - root element missing" followed by another high severity error that displays "Log file path must be defined before calling the WriteToLog method".

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this question is for http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 7):

Try to delete the file %Appdata%\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting settings.config file and other files yet it did not fix the issue.

For me once I uninstalled **MySql notifier** from control panel and reinstalled it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/notifier/ it worked fine.