# MySql Workbench: Log file path must be defined before calling the WriteToLog method error

Tags: mysql, windows-7, mysql-workbench

I am having MySQl WorkBench 6.1 CE and whenever my system starts it throws this error:

```
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbenchConnectionCollection.LoadXmlFile(Boolean saving)
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbenchConnectionCollection.Load()
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbench.LoadExternalConnections()
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbench.set_ExternalApplicationConnectionsFilePath(String value)
   at MySql.Notifier.Notifier.InitializeMySqlWorkbenchStaticSettings()
   at MySql.Notifier.Notifier..ctor()
   at MySql.Notifier.NotifierApplicationContext..ctor()
Log file path must be defined before calling the WriteToLog method
```

My system has MySQL Notifier 1.1.5 but it does not have any folder "Oracle"  or settings.config so the below results do not help me.

https://serverfault.com/questions/554869/mysql-startup-error-root-element-missing 
[MySQL Startup Error - Root element missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964869/mysql-startup-error-root-element-missing).

The OS is Win7 64 bit.

Please help!

Comment: Please try the latest Workbench version, which is 6.3.3 at the time of this writing. Workbench 6.1.x is no longer supported.

Comment: See [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/554869/75336).

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete the file `C:\Users\Administrator\%AppData%\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config"`.

The file will be regenerated when you reboot next time.

It works for me.

I tried reinstalling `MySQL Notifier` but it didn't work.

Comment: Worked great! It was MySQL Notifier reporting this and another error, deleting the config file did the trick, thank you very much for taking the time to jot it down here!